# JSON with array and non-array data with Groovy JsonBuilder

Tags: arrays, groovy, jsonbuilder

I need to create a JSON string in my Groovy script which has some elements that are array and some which are not. For example the below..

```
 {
 "fleet": {
   "admiral":"Preston",
   "cruisers":  [
      {"shipName":"Enterprise"},
      {"shipName":"Reliant"}
   ]
  }
}
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973342/how-to-use-groovy-builder-to-generate-an-array-type-json) but the answers either didn't make sense or didn't apply to my example.

I tried the below in code...

```
 def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
 def fleetStr = json.fleet {
         "admiral" "Preston"
         cruisers {
            {shipName: "[Enterprise]"},  {shipName: "[Reliant]"}
       }
   }
```

But it gives an exception...

```
 Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy, the `{}` syntax is used for closures. For objects in JSON, you want to use the map syntax `[:]`, and for lists, the list syntax `[]`:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def fleetStr = json.fleet {
    "admiral" "Preston"
    cruisers( [
        [shipName : "[Enterprise]"],
        [shipName: "[Reliant]"]
    ])
}

assert json.toString() == 
    '{"fleet":{"admiral":"Preston","cruisers":[{"shipName":"[Enterprise]"},{"shipName":"[Reliant]"}]}}'
```

---

**Update**: as per your follow-up, you need to use the same list syntax `[]` outside the `"[Enterprise]"` and `"[Reliant]"` strings:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def fleetStr = json.fleet {
    "admiral" "Preston"
    cruisers( [
        [shipName : ["Enterprise"]],
        [shipName: ["Reliant"]]
    ])
}

assert json.toString() == 
    '{"fleet":{"admiral":"Preston","cruisers":[{"shipName":["Enterprise"]},{"shipName":["Reliant"]}]}}'
```

Comment: thanks, just a follow up question (somewhat unrelated). Supposing I wanted the value of shipName to appear as an array element in the JSON even though it can have only value. For example  "shipName": ["Enterprise"], can you also help with how I can do this?